# How to make a div jump a row

Tags: html, css

I want my div to jump to the next row although there is enough room on the row for it to stay there. I have three boxes on the row and i am interested in making the last box jump to the next row. Each box is defined by itself with its own class. I've for now added a `<br/>` but I am looking for a way to this using CSS.

I've tried using `display: block` on the second div's class but it makes it jump a line too which is not what i want.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply add to the second div's class `clear:right` or you can add to the third div's class `clear:left` both should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Try using float and clear (both) CSS properties.